# Does weak convergence (of a periodic function) imply weak-* convergence for the derivative?

Tags: periodic-functions, weak-convergence

Lets assume we have $b(x,t) \in L^\infty$ periodic in x and $\frac{db}{dt} \in L^{p}, p\in\mathbb{N}$.

$b(x,t)$ converges weakly to an $f(t)=\int b(x,t)dx  \in L^q$ for all $1<q<\infty$.

Also, $\frac{db}{dt}$ converges weakly-* in $L^{p}$.

Does this mean that $\frac{db}{dt}$ is converging weakly-* to $\frac{df}{dt}$? Or can one achieve this with another assumption?